# Create new column in df based on conditional with strings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner to Pandas, so bear with me.

Here is a simplified version of my series:

| Name |
| --- |
| James |
| Michael |
| Jim |
| Bob |
| Jim |
| Bob |

I want to create a df that adds a column for 'Team.' Here is my team distribution:

```
team1 = [
    'Michael',
    'James',
  ]
team2 = [
    'Jim',
    'Bob'
]
```

My first instinct was to def func with an if statement and isin, like so:

```
def Team(row):
    if row['Name'].isin(team1):
        return 'Team 1'
    elif row['Name'].isin(team2):
        return 'Team 2'
    else:
        return 'No Team'

df['Team'] = df.apply(Team, axis=1)
df
```

With the axis, I get:
"TypeError: Teams() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"
When I remove the axis, I get:
"TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Any idea if there is a better approach? Thanks!

Comment: What is `df`? You've only mentioned a Series. If you called your Series `df`, that's really confusing. Please make a [mre] including complete code, desired output, and the [full error messages with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341).

Comment: I can reproduce the errors with `df = pd.Series(["James", "Michael", "Jim", "Bob", "Jim", "Bob"], name="Name")`. I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your errors, but I see that the error also shows `Teams()`, instead of `Team()`.

In any case, in your example, `row` is actually a pandas series, when you slice it, you get the actual strings, which does not have a method `isin()`. Changing your function definition should work:

```py
def Team(row):
    if row['Name'] in team1:
        return 'Team 1'
    elif row['Name'] in team2:
        return 'Team 2'
    else:
        return 'No Team'

df['Team'] = df.apply(Team, axis=1)
df
```

Let me also suggest using directly the pandas series, instead of the whole dataframe. That should be faster as well. The `.apply()` method for series are similar to the ones in dataframes but you won't need to pass the `axis=1` argument.

```py
def Team(name):
    if name in team1:
        return 'Team 1'
    elif name in team2:
        return 'Team 2'
    else:
        return 'No Team'

df['Team'] = df.Name.apply(Team)
df
```

Docs:

- [Pandas DataFrame `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
- [Pandas Series `apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: This works perfectly -- and thank you for the syntax suggestions, they are very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follow (I am using a simple example):

```
import pandas as pd

team1 = ["A", "B"]
team2 = ["C", "D"]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"]})
df.set_index("Name", inplace=True)

df.assign(Team=df.index.map(lambda x: "Team1" if x in team1 else "Team2" if x in team2 else "No Team"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
         Team
Name
A       Team1
B       Team1
C       Team2
D       Team2
E     No Team
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.merge` to help.  The advantage of this over `apply` is that it should be faster and more efficient with a larger dataset.

```
s = pd.Series(['James', 'Michael', 'Jim', 'Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob'], name='Name')
team1 = [
    'Michael',
    'James',
  ]
team2 = [
    'Jim',
    'Bob'
]
d = {
    'Team 1': team1, 
    'Team 2': team2
}

df = pd.DataFrame(s).merge(pd.DataFrame(d).melt().set_index('value'), right_index=True, left_on='Name').rename({'variable': 'Team'}, axis=1)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
      Name    Team
0    James  Team 1
1  Michael  Team 1
2      Jim  Team 2
3      Bob  Team 2
4      Jim  Team 2
5      Bob  Team 2
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this using a join. You can define your teams (or read it in from somewhere), create a temporary `df` and then join this onto your main `df`

```
# Define teams
teams = {
'Team 1': [
    'Michael',
    'James',
  ],
'Team 2': [
    'Jim',
    'Bob'
]
}
# Correct format for df creation
name_to_team = dict()
for team, names in teams.items():
 for name in names:
  name_to_team[name] = team

# Get df with name as index and 'Team' as the column
team_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(name_to_team, orient='index', columns=['Team'])

# Join df using 'Name'
df = df.merge(team_df, left_on='Name', right_index=True)
```

Comment: i dont think its worth create a new df just to do this.

Comment: I think this sort of thing should be done with joins, rather than applying a function, treating dataframes similarly to database tables to perform functions on. It gives more flexibility to generalise, add extra info in etc.

Comment: and I'd agree for a more complex data set, but if you can get away with apply on a dataset and a lambda function, it would perform much faster for a simple task like this.

Comment: Make sense, and if you're perfoming a transformation of existing data I would agree. However I think for any size of data frame for which the speed will be significantly different in the two approaches, using a lambda and a defined lookup is going to become unwieldy quickly vs. having a more database like approach